# Set PHP variable depending on input from form

Tags: php, html

testI need to set a variable depending on the option the user selects from a select box in a HTMLform.

HTML

```
 <form action="contact.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="contact_form" id="contact_form" novalidate>

               <select name="department" id="department">
                      <option value="0">Choose a department</option>
                      <option value="1">Enquiries</option>
                      <option value="2">Proposals</option>
                      <option value="3">Work</option>                                         
                </select>
```

PHP

```
$to = "test@machinas.com";
```

if value = 1 then `&to` should be enquiries@website.com.
if value = 2 then `&to` should be proposals@website.com.
if value = 3 then `&to` should be work@website.com.

Could I get a hand, I'm a front end and only have basic knowledge of PHP. Most of the PHP file is already coded to send an email but I'm missing this. Thanks!

Comment: `if (...) { $to = ... } else if (...) { $to = ... } ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
switch ($_POST['department']) {
  case 1:
    $to = 'enquiries@website.com';
    break;
  case 2:
    $to = 'proposals@website.com';
    break;
  case 3:
    $to = 'work@website.com';
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use a switch or if-condition

```
switch ($_GET['department']) {
    case '1':
        $to = "...";
        break;
    case '2':
        $to = "...";
        break;
    //....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a map of your values

```
 $map = array(
         0=>"",
         1=>"email1@somewhere.com",
         2=>"email2@somewhere.com",
         3=>"email3@somewhere.com",
         4=>"email4@somewhere.com");
```

then assign $to based on the matching post value

```
 $to = $map[(int)$_POST["department"]];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
<option value="email@mydomain.com">department</option>
```

and then get the post value.

Answer (score 0):

What about an associative array like below :

```
$emails = array( "1" => "enquiries@website.com", "2" => "proposals@website.com" , "3" => "work@website.com");

// and then 

$to = $emails[$_POST["department"]];
```